# increment a value in for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I have the following code for `for` loop, what I am trying to do is each time the loop runs the next `$data` needs to be the previous `$data * 1.025`

```
$amount = 3150;
$age=22;
for ($x = $age; $x<= 60; $x++){
    $data = $amount*1.025;
    echo "amount_$x = $data<br>";
}
```

This gives me the following outcome, which is understood because the value of `$data` never changes

```
amount_22 = 3228.75
amount_23 = 3228.75
amount_24 = 3228.75
amount_25 = 3228.75
```

where as the outcome i am looking for should be something like

```
amount_22 = 3228.75
amount_23 = 3309.47
amount_24 = 3392.20
amount_25 = 3477.01
```

I will appreciate any help in how to get the next value of `$data * 1.025`

Comment: you not assigning the new value to `$amount` in the for loop. Thats why it taking the default value which u given earlier.

Comment: What *should* happen if `$age > 60`?

Comment: If the age is > 60, the loop will stop

Comment: @kimbarcelona Thank you, Captain Obvious. I meant how the app should handle the situation.

Comment: loop should just stop when it reaches age 60, as data after that is not required

Comment: thank you all for your feedback, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$amount` doesn't change in your loop, so `$amount*1.025;` doesn't change either.  Try `$data = $data*1.025;`. Note you'll need to initialize `$data = $amount;`.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing `$data` based on the same variable `$amount`. Amount does not change in the loop, so the result is the same.

Try this:

```
$amount = 3150;
$age = 22;
for ($x = $age; $x <= 60; $x++){
    $amount = $amount*1.025;
    echo "amount_$x = $amount<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the code to this:

```
$amount = $amount*1.025;
echo "amount_$x = $amount<br>";
```

This will increment the `amount` each time, and changes will be retained since `amount` is declared outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Update `$amount` with each loop.

E.g.

```
$amount = 3150;
$age=22;
for ($x = $age; $x<= 60; $x++){
    $amount = $amount*1.025;
    echo "amount_$x = $amount<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said the new data has to be the previous data * 1.025, but you're multiplying `$amount` instead of `$data`.

```
$data = 3150;
$age=22;
for ($x = $age; $x<= 60; $x++){
    $data = $data*1.025;
    echo "amount_$x = $data<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A sweet solution is to assign a variable of the product of $amount and 1.025 for iteration so:

```
<?php

$amount = 3150;
$age=22;

for ($x = $age; $x<= 60; $x++){
    $amount = $amount * 1.025;
    echo "amount_$x = $amount<br>";
}
?>
```